# Extracting a value from all string records in a column Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have the following sample:

```
let data = datatable(ProducutName:string)
            [
                "Amigo Patchi 50 KG",
                "Amigo Patchi 50 KG",
                "Amigo Patchi 50 KG",
                "Chocolate Bar 25Kg",
                "Chocolate Bar 25Kg",  
                "Chocolate Bar 25Kg",  
                "Brownies CupCakes 100Kg",
                "Brownies CupCakes 100Kg",
                "Brownies CupCakes 100Kg"
            ];
```

In this sample, there are 3 different product lines:

- Amigo Patchi
- Chocolate Bar
- Brownies Cupcakes

Each of those product lines has in it its name and value. But as you can see, each product has the value and its unit written in a different way. What I am trying to achieve here is to extract this value from each of those records and display it in a new column. So the expected result would be two columns, first column: ProductName; second Column: Value

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this in Kusto ?

**Please take into consideration that the value for each line could change. It is not always the same. So the code that will be written should simply search for this value(searching for an integer) in the string and display it in a new column as shown in the screen shot.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### Option 1

[parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseoperator) operator

```
let data = datatable(ProductName:string)
            [
                "Amigo Patchi 50 KG",
                "Amigo Patchi 50 KG",
                "Amigo Patchi 50 KG",
                "Chocolate Bar 25Kg",
                "Chocolate Bar 25Kg",  
                "Chocolate Bar 25Kg",  
                "Brownies CupCakes 100Kg",
                "Brownies CupCakes 100Kg",
                "Brownies CupCakes 100Kg"
            ];
data
| parse kind=regex ProductName with ProductName @"\s+" Value:int @"\s*" Units
```

| ProductName | Value | Units |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Amigo Patchi | 50 | KG |
| Amigo Patchi | 50 | KG |
| Amigo Patchi | 50 | KG |
| Chocolate Bar | 25 | Kg |
| Chocolate Bar | 25 | Kg |
| Chocolate Bar | 25 | Kg |
| Brownies CupCakes | 100 | Kg |
| Brownies CupCakes | 100 | Kg |
| Brownies CupCakes | 100 | Kg |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA7WRvQrCQBCE%200DeYbjKvyIKNoqgprAQJI02arEmS3IY7%20RugxY%20vJrKFIKgTrOzwwdTTMmCjIQwqY/QoeRW4mxWpbKiE4%208OG3ydhjgRdvm%205SanXRukZCkhcYwwnKhen/H4sKmtiRhzMlhMFzmH2PAN%20Dc2YvR7BFX55iOD9OPojftv2Cb6H4cBs%205wuCGMznPOGqTTRznfMXLerhoKRrBVO18V2FDZcUjbaQOOgpro8XfAfqI5XsNAgAA)

###### Option 2

[extract_all()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/extractallfunction)

```
let data = datatable(ProductName:string)
            [
                "Amigo Patchi 50 KG",
                "Amigo Patchi 50 KG",
                "Amigo Patchi 50 KG",
                "Chocolate Bar 25Kg",
                "Chocolate Bar 25Kg",  
                "Chocolate Bar 25Kg",  
                "Brownies CupCakes 100Kg",
                "Brownies CupCakes 100Kg",
                "Brownies CupCakes 100Kg"
            ];
data
| project info = extract_all(@"(.*)\s+(\d+)\s*(.*)", ProductName)[0]
| project ProductName = info[0], Value = toint(info[1]), Units = toupper(info[2])
```

| ProductName | Value | Units |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Amigo Patchi | 50 | KG |
| Amigo Patchi | 50 | KG |
| Amigo Patchi | 50 | KG |
| Chocolate Bar | 25 | KG |
| Chocolate Bar | 25 | KG |
| Chocolate Bar | 25 | KG |
| Brownies CupCakes | 100 | KG |
| Brownies CupCakes | 100 | KG |
| Brownies CupCakes | 100 | KG |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA7WRQYvCMBCF74X%20h6GnRItUwYvLwq49eBDEi3vRIrNptmY3JiWdogd/vEn3Ug8LwupcJvPm4w3haUlQIiG8do3wU0u2drZsBa3wKGcNOWUqHkfQq%203tGCp5P6rKwhpJHBRMM1gukvTpWH6wwmokCXN0MJkuq7sxgP%20Ac2dPRskG8rbO8cc/xln2x/VHsLdo8RJHIa44ukDt7LcUBMp8WZ%20iPJNDQXvUmr0lbDTgu2bIduXQ90EY/Yd6%20fJtVvRdeitvFjw9kMIH6jYIZJUh1snjgqewMYqaTm/rWrrfzaTgV/9LUJ1XAgAA)